# Cant assign values from a json response in angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular

I trying to assign values after subscribing to the response that i am reciving from my GET request to my NodeJS server, But i keep getting `undefined`, And i cant understand why.

Those are the variables that i want to assign values to them:

```
 movie:any
 showHalls:any
```

The `.subscribe` inside the  `ngOnInit`  function

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.showService.getShowByMovieId(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe(
      data=> 
      { 
       this.showHalls = data.showsHall
       this.movie     = data.movie;

      },
  );
```

The Get request inside my server:

```
getShowByMovieId(id): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.getShowByMovieIdUrl + id)
}
```

The route in NodeJs

```
router.get('/showbymovieid:id', function (req, res, next) {
    Shows.find({ movie: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) }).populate('movie').populate('showsHall').exec(function (err, foundShow) {
        if (err) return next(err)
        res.json(foundShow)
    })
})
```

The Json file

```
[
    {
        "showsHall": [
            {
                "_id": "5b64cb758ad5f81a6cb7e6ae",
                "hallName": "Big Hall",
                "rows": 10,
                "seats": 15,
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "movie": [
            {
                "associatedToShow": true,
                "_id": "5b64d3968a0b995afc12f03d",
                "movieName": "Whitny",
                "directorName": "Kevin Macdonald",
                "movieDescription": "Nice Movie",
                "movieImg": "uploads\\474064ac3999bda872d37a992bdd01dd",
                "updated_date": "2018-08-03T22:13:42.944Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "takenSeats": [],
        "_id": "5b64d3ca8a0b995afc12f03f",
        "showDate": "8/5/2018",
        "showStartTime": "1:14 AM",
        "showEndTime": "1:14 AM",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

This is How the data looks like when i console log it

[image]

Comment: At what point are the values undefined? Are you seeing that in your template? Or in some other code that is not shown? Also, it looks like you are receiving an array? What does `data` look like within your subscribe?

Comment: The values are undefined everywhere, Even inside the .subscribe.
I added a pic of the 'data' , When i console log it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is `Array` but you are treating that as `Object`.

In your subscription to API call observable, try

`this.showHalls = data[0].showsHall;
this.movie     = data[0].movie;`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, So to turn it into a Object i can only use a foorLoop?

Comment: Well, it depends. If the API is under your control and you know you will _always_ be returning one object, change the API. Otherwise, yes, for loop.